# If $X \sim X^2$, then $X$ is independent of itself?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ - random variable, which has same distribution as $X^2$. Is $X$ must be independent of itself? Any Hint?

Edit:
I want to show that if $X \sim X^2$ then $\mathbb{E}(x)^2 = \mathbb{E}(x^2)$?

Comment: How can $X$ be independent of itself?

Comment: @JohnGowers  Well, no.  It should mean that $P(X=x,X=y)=P(X=x)\times P(X=y)\,\forall x,y$ but that implies that $X$ is a constant variable (at least it is constant with probability $1$).  Given the other information, we'd conclude that $X$ was either the constant $0$ or $1$ .  But I can't believe that this is what the OP has in mind.

Comment: I see the edit, and the answer is clearly no.  take any Bernoulli process ($P(X=1)=p,P(X=0)=1-p$).  Then $X^2=X,\,E(X)=E(X^2)=p$ but $E(X)^2=p^2$.

Comment: @lulu it technically would be if it had 0 bits of information, since then it's mutual information with itself wound be 0 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that $X$ is independent from $X^2$ the answer is NO.

Consider a fair coin.

$X=1$ with $p=0.5$ and $X=0$ o.w.

Then clearly $X \sim X^2$ and $X$ is not independent from itself.

---

But if you interest in some $X$ which is independent from itself I suggest to read this wiki page:

[Kolmogorov's zero–one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law)

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be the distribution function of $X$. Because $X\sim X^2$, clearly $\Bbb P[X\ge 0]=1$. For $x>0$, you have $F(x) =\Bbb P[X\le x]=\Bbb P[X^2\le x] =\Bbb P[X\le\sqrt{x}]=F(\sqrt{x})$. Consequently, $F(x)=F(x^{1/2^n})$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Now let $n\to\infty$ and examine the cases $0<x<1$ and $x>1$ separately, to obtain $F(x)=F(1-)$ for $0<x<1$ and $F(x)=F(1)$ for $x\ge 1$.
It now follows easily that $\Bbb P[X=0$ or $1]=1$. Thus @Leila's example is the most general case.